# how to make the inequality in this trigonometry question?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

The diagram shows the curve $y= \sin(4x)*10e^{-x/2}$ for $x \ge 0$.The stationary points are labelled as $T_1, \ T_2, \ T_3, \dots$ as shown. The x-coordinates of $T_1$ and $T_2$ are $0.362$ and $1.147$ respectively. It is given that x-coordinate of $T_n$ is greater than $25$.Find the least possible value of $n$.

Attempted Solution:
[image]

Comment: yes its by differentiating the equation i can find the x-coordinates of any T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sin 4x \cdot 10e^{-x/2}$. Then,
$$
f'(x)=(4\cos 4x-1/2\sin 4x)\cdot 10e^{-x/2}.
$$
So, $f'(x)=0$ when $\sin 4x=8\cos 4x$ or, in other words, $\tan 4x = 8$. A solution to this inequality is 
$$
x=\frac{\arctan 8}{4},$$
but remember that $\tan x$ is $\pi$-periodic, so the $x$ coordinate of the peak $T_k$ is given by $$x_k=\frac{\arctan 8 + (k-1)\pi}{4}.$$

Thus, your problem now is to find the minimum $k$ such that the above expression exceeds $25$, but at this point this is easy:
$$
25\leq \frac{\arctan 8 + (k-1)\pi}{4} \Leftrightarrow \frac{100 -\arctan 8}{\pi}+1 \leq k.$$

Comment: And it is even simpler if you consider that $\tan^{-1}(8)\approx \frac{\pi}{2}$ and that $\pi\approx \frac{22}7$ ! I am really lazy !! Cheers :-)